# To show something are appearing n-times!

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators, unicode-math, mathtools

Suppose I want to write that the sequence 1,1,...,1 appear n-times. How will I do this? Usually in mathematics we use a braces at the bottom and write "n-times" below the brace.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `\underbrace` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %for \text
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\text{eat pizza},\text{eat pizza}, \ldots , 
            \text{eat pizza}}_{n \text{ times}}
\]
\end{document}
```

It's probably worth taking a look at the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort); `\underbrace` is covered on page 57.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you mean that your sequence is the finite constant sequece consisting of n ones, you would notate it as you mentioned it. The way to get this in LaTeX is simple:

```
\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{n\text{-times}}
```

Comment: You need to load the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package for `\text`.

Comment: You are totally right. As far as the question is tagged with amsmath i thought it would be obsolete to write it down.

Comment: @Ruben complete MWE's are always better than single lines :)

Answer (score 2):

For a finite constant sequence, you can write (load `amsmath` and `amssymb` package):

```
\[f:A\to\{1\}\qquad(A=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{N},\,x\leq n\})\]
```

[image]